# In sklearn.linear_model.Ridge, what exactly is the solverparameter doing?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, regression, linear-regression

In the `sklearn.linear_model.Ridge` method, there is a parameter, `solver : {‘auto’, ‘svd’, ‘cholesky’, ‘lsqr’, ‘sparse_cg’, ‘sag’, ‘saga’}`.
And according to the [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.Ridge.html#sklearn.linear_model.Ridge), we should choose different parameter depending on different types' values which is dense or sparse or just use `auto`.
So in my opinion, we just choose a specific parameter to make calculations fast to corresponding data.
Are my thoughts right or wrong?
If not mind, could anyone give me some advice because I didn't search and get anything proving my thoughts or not?
Sincerely thanks.

Comment: It is not only about speed, some methods can be more sensitive or more stable in some specific situations, like for instance if you deal with singular matrices. Different methods may also have different properties with respect to their guarantee to converge or not. When you don't know much about optimization techniques, your best bet is to go with `auto`.

Answer (score 0):

You are almost right.
Some solver work only with specific type of data (dense vs. sparse) or specific type of problem (non-negative weights).

However for many cases you can use multiple solvers (e.g. for sparse problems you have at least `sag`, `sparse_cg` and `lsqr`). These solvers have different characteristics and some of them might work better in some cases and some of them work better in other cases. In some cases some solvers even do not converge.

In many cases, the simple engineering-like answer is to use solver which works best on your data. You just test all of them and measure time to answer.

If you want, more precise answer you should dig into documentation of referenced methods (e.g. `scipy.sparse.linalg.lsqr`).